# angular 7 radio [attr.avlue] breaks [ngModel] functionality

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button

I have a list with 4 radio input element, generated by *ngFor.
on each radio element when I user `ngModel` with `[attr.value]="ans.name"`
this is not working until I user `value="{{ans.name}}"`

Below is the breaking code example.

```
<li *ngFor="let ans of question.answers; let i = index;">
  <label class="custom-radio" [attr.tabindex]="i+1" [attr.for]="'op-'+i"> {{ans.name}}
    <input type="radio" name="answer" [attr.value]="ans.name" [attr.checked]="selectedAnswer === ans.name" [attr.id]="'op-'+i" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswer">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</li>
```

And here is working example.

```
<li *ngFor="let ans of question.answers; let i = index;">
  <label class="custom-radio" [attr.tabindex]="i+1" [attr.for]="'op-'+i"> {{ans.name}}
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{ans.name}}" [attr.checked]="selectedAnswer === ans.name" [attr.id]="'op-'+i" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswer">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</li>
```

I'm not getting it really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the DOM native properties must not be set with `[attr.value]` but simply with `[value]`, `[id]`, `[name]` or whatever the property is. The `value="{{ans.name}}"` syntax is also valid (if it's a `string` type), but the double mustache syntax is preferrable for string templating, in your case `[value]="ans.name"` is better.

The `[attr.my-attr]` syntax is for custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute binding is used to bind an attribute property of a view element. Value is a native element of DOM which shouldn't be a part of attribute. Attribute binding is mainly useful where we don’t have any property view with respect to an HTML element attribute.

For example in table td colspan is an attribute. So u can use [attr.colspan]

Property binding is, passing the data from the component class and set the value to the given element in the view. So the value should be a property binding or sring interpolation

Answer (score 0):

The `value` is a property of the radio. You can use property binding with the square bracket syntax to bind it to a property of the component class or a template variable. You can use interpolation only for primitive type data. It works but is not the ideal way to do it.

```
<li *ngFor="let ans of question.answers; let i = index;"> <label class="custom-radio" [attr.tabindex]="i+1" [attr.for]="'op-'+i"> {{ans.name}} <input type="radio" name="answer" [value]="ans.name" [attr.checked]="selectedAnswer === ans.name" [attr.id]="'op-'+i" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswer"> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official way to do this.Using [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#injecting-attribute-values). It is a simple method. See [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#injecting-attribute-values) on how to implement.

```
import { Attribute, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-input-with-attribute-decorator',
  template: '<input type="{{type}}">'
})
export class MyInputWithAttributeDecoratorComponent {
  constructor(@Attribute('type') public type: string) { }
}
```

In the parent component:

```
<app-my-input-with-attribute-decorator type="number"></app-my-input-with-attribute-decorator>
```